# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu, sqlite3

Tenho o código abaixo supostamente simples. 
O intuíto é criar uma tabela incluir valores e logo após mostrar as informações, mas no **log** do apache está mostrando o seguinte:

> ```
> [:error] [pid 17622] [client 10.1.21.1:42895] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/acesso.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/acesso.php on line 2
> ```

```
<?php   
  $db = new SQLite3('test.db');

  $db->exec('CREATE TABLE test (id INT, message STRING)');

  $db->exec("INSERT INTO test (id, message) VALUES ('1', 'test message')");
  $db->exec("INSERT INTO test (id, message) VALUES ('2', 'test message 2')");

  $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID = 2");

  print_r($results->fetchArray());

?>
```

> Verão do PHP : 7.0
>
> Versão do OS : Ubuntu 16.10
>
> Versão do Sqlite instalado: 3.14.1
>
> Versão do Apache: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Dá um phpinfo() e vê se o modo sqlite tá instalado

Comment: Depois de utilizar o phpinfo() e confirmar que a extensão para o SQLite não está activada basta retirar o comentário "extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll" no php.ini e reiniciar o apache

Comment: descomentei, reiniciei o serviço e o erro continua.

Comment: Você vai ter que reiniciar o seu servidor, já que o PHP pode ter sido instalado como uma variável de ambiente do servidor, não só do Apache/IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você ativou o módulo de sqlite3 no PHP7 do Ubuntu?

Para ativar, só ir no servidor e digitar no console:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3
```

Vê se resolve, se não verifica os módulos do Apache, no Ubuntu ele tem o comando `a2enmod` que você pode usar para ativar módulos.

Comment: é bem provável que seja mesmo falta de rodar o `a2enmod` ;)

Comment: No meu caso também foi necessário fazer um reload das configurações do apache. /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Answer (score 0):

ali está falando que não está achando a classe SQLite3.
Você pode usar um include_once(arquivo_da_classe)para testar

Comment: Problema resolvido com a Instância da classe a ainda assim tinha permissão do diretório que precisei alterar